# Running a command at startup

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, sysvinit

How would I go about running a command at startup in ArchLinux using `Systemd` like `rc.local` in `Sysv`?

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the command. For the most common cases, you *don't* need a command.

- If you want to adjust a sysctl (a file in `/proc/sys`), those can be configured in **`/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf`** (generally `99-sysctl.conf` or `99-local.conf`; [manual page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html)):

  ```
  kernel.sysrq = 1
  kernel.pid_max = 4194304
  ```
- If it's a module parameter under `/sys/modules`, it should be set when the module is first loaded, in **`/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`** (generally `modprobe.conf`; see manual page):

  ```
  options kafs rootcell=stacken.kth.se
  ```
- If you want to write to a device parameter in `/sys`, or if you want to run a program to change the device's settings, write an *udev* rule that would do this when the device is plugged in and put it in **`/etc/udev/rules.d/*.rules`**. The manual page is `udev(7)`, and you'll find `udevadm info` useful when trying to match the right device.

  ```
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="eth*", \
      RUN+="/usr/bin/ethtool -s %k wol d"

  # This rule checks if a device has an attribute in its /sys subdir:
  ACTION=="add", \
      SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_host", \
      TEST=="link_power_management_policy", \
      ATTR{link_power_management_policy}="medium_power"
  ```
- If you want to write to a file anywhere else, or create a file or directory, use `/etc/tmpfiles.d` ([manual page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html)).
- If you want to *load* a module, put its name in a file in **`/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf`** ([manual page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/modules-load.d.html)).
- Finally, if you want to run a general command or start a daemon, write a `.service` unit file ([one of many manual pages](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)). Put it in **`/etc/systemd/system/*.service`**, and use the many examples in `/lib/systemd/system`. It'll be managed through `systemctl`.

  A few things to note: the **`Type=`** parameter has to be set right (`simple` vs `forking` vs `oneshot`), and the `ExecStart=` parameter requires a simple command line and does not accept shell-like syntax (no `>`, no `&&`, no `$(...)` and so on, only simple `$ENVVAR` and `%x`.)

  It is possible to order services after a specific device appears, using `After=name.device` (e.g. `After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device`).

Both **#archlinux** and **#systemd** have their IRC channels on the *freenode* network.

Comment: It's a daemon I want to run, I attempted creating a service file but it seemed to hang or something and would never run the command but it worked if I ran it manually. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: @JordanDoyle: You might find [this blog post](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html) useful. Pay also close attention to the **`Type=`** parameter in `systemd.service(5)`. Also try to ask Arch's IRC channel or forums, as systemd units should be part of the package just like rc.d scripts once were.